# Is there a sound name for 's', 'z', 'sh', 'ch' and 'j'

Tags: single-word-requests

I know the sound name of 's' or 'sh' is called sibilant. This pronunciation name is useful and could be used to summarize the pronunciation rules, instead of listing all the individual letters.

But for this list - 's', 'z', 'sh', 'ch' and 'j'(/dʒ/) , what is their sound name? If there is no such a single name to cover them all, what's the descriptive language for them?

This list is special because the final 's' at the end of their plural forms is pronounced as /əz/.

Comment: You are wrong about a word ending "sh" (like *crash*) being pronounced /əz/. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology for some names. It's not exactly clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. Edit again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Wikipedia page on [English phonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology) has the following:

> - **s**: /s/ unvoiced alveolar fricative
> - **z**: /z/ voiced alveolar fricative
> - **sh**: /ʃ/ unvoiced post-alveolar fricative
> - **ch**: /tʃ/ unvoiced post-alveolar affricate
> - **j**: /dʒ/ voiced post-alveolar affricate

There’s also the terminal sound in a word like *luge* (the tobogganing sport):

> - /ʒ/ voiced post-alveolar fricative [that is, related to /ʃ/]

However they are all ***sibilants*** and listed as such in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant).

Comment: These are precisely the sounds that produce automatic insertion of epenthetic /ə/ in the Noun Plural, Noun Possessive, and Verb Present Tense morphemes. Because these are all /z/, and it's very hard to pronounce two sibilants together and hear the difference.

Comment: @JohnLawler Difficult for English speakers, anyway. Japanese has minimal pairs like _shi_ and _sushi_ which are moderately difficult for English speakers to hear and very difficult to pronounce because of the unvoiced _U_ in _sushi._

Comment: Sure, but Japanese speakers have lots more phonetic details to cue on than English speakers.